# Fragment no view found for ID in android when view id is changed it shows both screens on same as overwritten?

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments

[this is the screenshot of overwritten screen of both fragments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/raCIi.jpg)I had searched on the sites, but I am unable to find the solution, here is my code:

```
public class MyLawyerFragment extends Fragment {
ImageButton im1;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_mylawyer,
            container, false);
    im1 = (ImageButton) v1.findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
    im1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Fragment fragment = new tasks();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.drawer_layout, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();

        }
    });
    return v1;
}
```

}

And here is my next fragment code, to which I want to go from the last one:

```
public class tasks extends Fragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    {

        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        final View rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_addlawyer, container, false);



    return rootview;
}}}
```

Here is the xml of task fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout

android:id="@+id/rel3"
android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="ADD LAWYER"
    android:id="@+id/textView29"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="#a8a8a8"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView29"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
<TextView
    android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="58dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="Email ID :"
    android:id="@+id/textView30"
    android:layout_marginStart="31dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="18dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_border_edittext"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editText31"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView30"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView30"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView30" />

<Button
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:background="@drawable/mybuttonred"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="CANCEL"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:id="@+id/button6"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText32"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/editText32"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button5" />

<Button
    android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
    android:background="@drawable/mybuttongreen"
    android:layout_width="160dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="SAVE LAWYER DETAILS"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:id="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_marginTop="29dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="Phone Number :"
    android:id="@+id/textView31"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText31"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText31"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText31" />

<EditText
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="18dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_border_edittext"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editText32"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView31"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView31"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView31" />
```

Now I am having this error in logcat:

```
Process: com.orion.android.mylawyerdiary, PID: 5453
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0d006c (com.orion.android.mylawyerdiary:id/rel3) for fragment tasks{22ba0560 #1 id=0x7f0d006c}
```

And I am unable to solve it...please somebody help me out.

This is the xml for my navigation drawer activity from where all fragments are connected:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start"
>

   <include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

   <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:theme="@style/NavigationDrawerStyle"
    android:background="#2B292A"
    app:itemTextColor="#ffffff"
    app:itemIconTint="#C09E57"
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/activity_navdrawer_header"
    app:menu="@menu/menu_navdrawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: clean your project and rebuild it

Comment: Is `rel3` id present in `activity_mylawyer` .xml?

Comment: @R.Zagórski no, rel3 id is present only in addlawyer.xml

Comment: @masoudvali i tried that way also, but it didn't worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the line as per edit and modified the onCreate method in addlawyer fragment by adding this

```
if (container != null) {
        container.removeAllViews();
    }
```

And it removed all other view so that only that fragment is shown which i choose.

Answer (score 2):

remove  this line       `super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);` 
on your tasks class

Because if you call super.onCreateView method,it will return null for your fragment's view. Those line below that line will not be called.

Edit :
okay, I guess you have contain_main.xml file 
update this line             `fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.rel3, fragment);`
 to `fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_container, fragment)`

Comment: @Linh Nguyen i removed that line from tasks.java but unfortunately it didn't worked and i got the same error as earlier.

Comment: fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.rel3, fragment); also is wrong, what is your view container for fragment ? Post your activity please

Comment: I want to go from MyLawyerFragment to task fragment, i had already posted their codes in question. Can you tell me an effective way to go from one fragment to another fragment without having that null view error.

Comment: But I cant not see your activity, because this line is wrong :fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.rel3, fragment); R.id.rel3 must be your view container in activity class. and what's xml name for task fragment?

Comment: final View rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_addlawyer, container, false);
must be replace R.layout.activity_addlawyer with xml file for task fragment. can you post activity_addlawyer.xml file ?

Comment: i had already posted activity_addlawyer.xml file in the question

Comment: what is your xml for Activity because fragmentTransaction.replace(...) must use view holder from activity

Comment: do you mean xml file for MyLawyerFragment?

Comment: I mean xml file for you activity ? where is your Activity not fragment

Comment: I have activity in my navigation drawer only

Comment: i followed your way but its showing red error mark on content_container on the same line which you told to do.

Comment: i solved the issue by myself, thanks for your efforts

Answer (score 0):

When replacing the fragment following code is invoked:

```
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.rel3, fragment);
```

What this means is that `Activity`'s view that is identified by ID `rel3` should be replaced by `fragment`.

Inside the `.xml` view of `Acitivty` (passed to `setContentView` method)   there should be a view with ID `rel3` that will be replaced by `fragment`.

Comment: so how to create that view? Sorry, i am a newbie actually!

Comment: i couldn't understand :( its so confusing